# There is some error in the style.xml file in my Android App

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-xml, android-styles

I have two styles in my App (`style.xml` file). This is the code that I wrote.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Splash.Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

And I get some error in the log. I have clicked a pic of it too.

[image]

And I want a dark (Black) action bar......so i don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below style

```
 <style name="Splash.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

**Edit code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: what do i do if i need a black colour action bar?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use AppCompatActivity, so all is clear, you need to use AppCompat theme, so change please

```
<style name="Splash.Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
<style name="Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

on

```
<style name="Splash.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<style name="Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Or if you want themes not changin on AppCompat, then you can extend from other activity.

**UPDATED**

This info if you want change color of your action bar.

If you use SDK level >= 21, then you need to provide attributes `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` in your theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item> 
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>
```

If your SDK level < 21, then I suggest you to update it :), or write something like:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle"   tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
```

Comment: As I said, you can not change your style, but simply extends not from AppCompatActivity, as there is no way to extends from AppCompatActivity and provide not Theme.AppCompat. Also I will update my answer about color of action bar, please,check

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending homescreen activity with AppCompatActivity change it to Activity

or change your theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Use 1) Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

2) Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar